# How to add DataRow in string of arrray

Tags: c#

In the DataTable i have n number rows want add those rows in array?

Comment: Your DataTable _is_ an array.

Comment: Do you feel any of the answers below accurately answer your question? If not, please try to clarify your question, so a more accurate answer can be given.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Rows
```

`Rows` is array of your records...

Answer (score 0):

The code below stores all the information in a datatable in a double array of strings. The code should be plug-and-play, just make sure you swap out "dataTable1" with the name of your actual DataTable.

```
string[,] stringArray = new string[dataTable1.Rows.Count, dataTable1.Columns.Count];

for (int row = 0; row < dataTable1.Rows.Count; ++row)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < dataTable1.Columns.Count; col++)
   {
      stringArray[row, col] = dataTable1.Rows[row][col].ToString();
   }
}
```

To access the first item out of *stringArray*, simply use call the code below, using the indices as you would for a normal array.

```
stringArray[0, 0]
```